# clearing Notifications from server after opening it

Tags: ios, swift, notifications

I have an iOS app that receives push notifications. It does that by registering to the database with `deviceToken` in `didRegisterUserForNotificationsSettings`. After that, when i send a notification it is received and when i open the app i clear them, in `applicationDidBecomeActive`. 
When sending a notification, my database updates the notification count. e.x. phone A got 3 notifications and phone B got 2. (related to `deviceToken`) if on phone A i open a notification it should send a message to the server with the same `deviceToken` to subtract 1 notification from its count on the database.

However i cannot figure out how to get the `deviceToken` in `applicationDidBecomeActive`.

Any other solution to my problem is not easy to be found (at least i couldn't).
How can i fix this issue, or how have other people addressed this problem to where you subtract the notifications count form the database upon opening a notification.

Please note that my database is in `mySQL` (1st normal form), and i connect with it using `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your device token using NSUserDefaults

Set this in your didRegisterUserForNotificationsSettings

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceTokenString forKey:kDeviceToken];
```

And this in you didBecoming Active.

```
NSString *deviceToken = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:kDeviceToken];
if (deviceToken != nil)
{
  // Call your API
}
```